# Submitting form and writing to a file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to get a form to write to a text file using PHP. That works fine but the page reloads to a blank page.

Now we already have a message that appears after the form is submitted using jQuery. The goal is to make it so the page doesn't reload and the jQuery message fades in. Now I'm not sure if AJAX is they way to do it but here is my JS and HTML:

HTML:

```
<form action="form.php" method="post" name="rsvp">

                    <div id="name-block">

                        <input type="text" name="fullName" placeholder="Full Name" id ="full-name" class="textBox" tabindex="1"/>
                        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" id ="email" class="textBox" tabindex="2"/>

                    </div>

                    <label class="form-title" id="numbOfAttendees" >Number of Attendees</label>

                    <div id="attendance-block" class="form-categories">
                        <input type="number" min="1" name="attend" placeholder="eg:1" id ="numAttend" class="textBox" tabindex="6">
                    </div>

                    <div id="submit-block">
                        <h6 class="form-title" id="sposnorship">Can you help us out as a sponsor?</h6>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sponsor" value="Yes" class="radio" id="sponsor">
                        <button type="submit" id = "button" >Submit</button>

                    </div>

                </form>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    $('form').bind('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({type: 'POST',
        url: '../form.php',
        data: 
        });
     });

 });
```

Comment: use
`return false`

which will stop your page from reloading

Comment: added it takes me to a white page.

Comment: It looks like your JavaScript indentation could do with fixing (I've done so). That will help both you and us.

Comment: Your `data` key needs something to be passed here - `{}` maybe? Don't forget to check your browser console for JavaScript errors.

Answer (score 1):

You should listen for the form's `submit` event rather than the `click` event using [jQuery's `submit` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('form').submit(function(event){
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '../form.php',
      data: {}
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});

});
```

When you `event.preventDefault` on the click event, you're just stopping the form's click event but the form's default submit event still triggers (causing a page reload).

#### JSFiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/pbhLpLay/

Comment: when i get it to not reload the page it doesnt write to the file but when i get it to write to the file it reloads. I tried the code but its still giving a white page.

Comment: @Indrick Open developer tools, go to the "Network" tab and see if the AJAX request is sending. Also check in the "Console" tab to see if there are any JS errors.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the page reloading use return false instead of .preventDefault()

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

  $('form').on('submit', function(event){

    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../form.php',
    data: {}
    });
   return false;
 });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way

`<script>`

`$("#button").click(function () {`

`var fullname=$('#full-name').val();`

`var email=$('#email').val();`

`var number=$('#numAttend').val();`

`var sponsor=$('#sponsor').val();`

`$.ajax({`
`type: 'POST',`
`url: '../form.php',` 
`data: {fullname1:fullname,email1:email,number1:number,sponsor1:sponsor},`
`success: function(data) {`
    `}`
    `});`
  `});` 
        `</script>`

Comment: To format blocks of code here, just select the code and click the code button. Backticking every line is not necessary, and it doesn't look as good.

Comment: please mention what are the necessary things?

Comment: I just did: just select the code and click the code button. It will indent the code by four spaces, which in Markdown turns it into code. You'll need to remove the backticks to repair this, unfortunately.